# Inverting the "numpy.ma.compressed" operation

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I want to create an array from a compressed masked array and a corresponding mask. Its easier to explain this with an example:

```
>>> x=np.ma.array(np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)), mask = [[True,True],[False,False]])
>>> y=x.compressed()
>>> y
array([ 2,  3])
```

Now I want to create an array in the same shape as x where the masked values get a standard value (for example -1) and the rest is filled up with a given array. It should work like this:

```
>>> z = decompress(y, mask=[[True,True],[False,False]], default=-1)
>>> z
array([[-1, -1],
       [ 2,  3]])
```

The question is: Is there any method like "decompress", or do i need to code it myself? In Fortran this is done by the methods "pack" and "unpack".
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I've answered a number of `ma` questions I'm by no means an expert with it.  But I'll explore the issue

Let's generalize your a array a bit:

```
In [934]: x=np.ma.array(np.arange(6).reshape((2,3)), mask = [[True,True,False],[False,False,True]])
In [935]: x
Out[935]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- 2]
 [3 4 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [936]: y=x.compressed()
In [937]: y
Out[937]: array([2, 3, 4])
```

`y` has no information about `x` except a subset of values.  Note it is 1d

`x` stores its values in 2 arrays (actually these are properties that access underlying `._data`, `._mask` attributes):

```
In [938]: x.data
Out[938]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [939]: x.mask
Out[939]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

My guess is that to `de-compress` we need to make a `empty` masked array with the correct dtype, shape and mask, and copy the values of `y` into its `data`.  But what values should be put into the masked elements of `data`?

Or another way to put the problem - is it possible to copy values from `y` back onto `x`?

A possible solution is to copy the new values to `x[~x.mask]`:

```
In [957]: z=2*y
In [958]: z
Out[958]: array([4, 6, 8])
In [959]: x[~x.mask]=z
In [960]: x
Out[960]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- 4]
 [6 8 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [961]: x.data
Out[961]: 
array([[0, 1, 4],
       [6, 8, 5]])
```

Or to make a new array

```
In [975]: w=np.zeros_like(x)
In [976]: w[~w.mask]=y
In [977]: w
Out[977]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- 2]
 [3 4 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [978]: w.data
Out[978]: 
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 0]])
```

Another approach is to make a regular array, `full` with the invalid values, copy `y` in like this, and turn the whole thing into a masked array.  It's possible that there is a masked array constructor that lets you specify the valid values only along with the mask.  But I'd have to dig into the docs for that.

===============

Another sequence of operations that will do this, using `np.place` for set values

```
In [1011]: w=np.empty_like(x)
In [1014]: np.place(w,w.mask,999)
In [1015]: np.place(w,~w.mask,[1,2,3])
In [1016]: w
Out[1016]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- 1]
 [2 3 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [1017]: w.data
Out[1017]: 
array([[999, 999,   1],
       [  2,   3, 999]])
```

====================

Look at

```
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py 
class _MaskedBinaryOperation:
```

This class is used to implement masked `ufunc`.  It evaluates the `ufunc` at valid cells (non-masked) and returns a new masked array with the valid ones, leaving the masked values unchanged (from the original)

For example with a simple masked array, `+1` does not changed the masked value.

```
In [1109]: z=np.ma.masked_equal([1,0,2],0)
In [1110]: z
Out[1110]: 
masked_array(data = [1 -- 2],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 0)
In [1111]: z.data
Out[1111]: array([1, 0, 2])
In [1112]: z+1
Out[1112]: 
masked_array(data = [2 -- 3],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 0)
In [1113]: _.data
Out[1113]: array([2, 0, 3])
In [1114]: z.compressed()+1
Out[1114]: array([2, 3])
```

`_MaskedUnaryOperation` might be simpler to follow, since it only has to work with 1 masked array.

Example, regular log has problems with the masked 0 value:

```
In [1115]: z.log()
...
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[1116]: 
masked_array(data = [0.0 -- 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 0)
```

but the masked log skips the masked entry:

```
In [1117]: np.ma.log(z)
Out[1117]: 
masked_array(data = [0.0 -- 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 0)
In [1118]: _.data
Out[1118]: array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.69314718])
```

---

oops - `_MaskedUnaryOperation` might not be that useful.  It evaluates the `ufunc` at all values `np.ma.getdata(z)`, with a `errstate` context to block warnings.  It then uses the mask to copy masked values on to the result (`np.copyto(result, d, where=m)`).

Comment: Whoa.. that's a huge load of information! The "np.place" now did the trick for me! Thanksalot!